# How to open image with uri like "content://" in default gallery app?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, uri, android-contentresolver

In my app I select an image from gallery. After, when the user click on it, I want to open the image with an app that handle images.
In android kitkat 4.4 I have a "content://" uri. When I try this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

The gallery app doesn't show me the image but a blank screen with an error message.
How can I open this kind of Uri with an intent?

Comment: The Uri that I receive is: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:30506

Comment: Did you solve this problem?? I am having the same issue

Comment: @MdOmarFaroqueAnik I created an activity to show the pictures using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)